# Modify frames of the cell's subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, frame, custom-cell

My table view consists of custom cells with several subviews.
Let call two of these subviews AView and BView. They are placed side by side.
There are some cases when I don't want to display BView (I make it hidden). But that means that I should make Aview wider by the width of BView.

I've tried to change the frame of the AView in the `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of my data source. No results.  Then I'd tried to change it in the `– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` of my delegate.  Failed again.
In both cases AView has the same size as in Storyboard.

So, where should I change the frame of AView?

Comment: can you post code how did you change the width of Aview?

Comment: is your custom cell made on xib ?

Comment: @anhtu, `AView.frame = newCalculatedFrame;`. newCalculatedFrame can be any frame. `CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` for example. The size doesn't change.

Comment: @Mr.T, I use storyboard.

Comment: is the Aview declared as IBoutlet in your tablecell ?

Comment: @Mr.T, no. I'm taking it from tag. `[cell viewWithTag:AVIEW_TAG];`

Comment: can you please show your cell for row index path mehtod with the code how you reference the cell  subviews with tag

Comment: Tags is such an ugly way to go about this. It's error prone when you add and removes views and is hard to read as it makes `cellForRow...` really fat and dense. Get used to always subclassing custom cells you will be happier in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that. One suggestion that I think is very clean is to:

1. Subclass UITableViewCell... Call it MyCell for example.
2. Create an `IBOutlet` in `MyCell` that links to the width constraint of BView. Call it BViewWidthConstraint.
3. In `MyCell` create the following function:

   ```
   func hideBView() -> void {
       self.BViewWidthConstraint.constant = 0
   }
   ```
4. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can now do:

   ```
   if needToHideBView {
       cell.hideBView()
   }
   ```

I am assuming that you are using Autolayout and that you set it up correctly!

Comment: So, the point is to change constraint. But why can't I modify frame?  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You can modify the frame but in that case you need to modify the frame of AView and potentially other stuff